# I need to delete a drop down list from an .xls file using Java code

Tags: java, excel, validation, dropdown

This is what I tried and it doesn't seem to work.

```
HSSFSheet hssfStationSheet = workbook.getSheet("NameOfTheSheet");
        CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 60, 0, 50);
        DVConstraint dvConstraint = DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint(new String[]{"10","20","30"});
        DataValidation dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressList, dvConstraint);
        dataValidation.setEmptyCellAllowed(true);
        dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
        dataValidation.setShowPromptBox(false);
        for(int index; index <= hssfSheet.getLastRowNum(); index++) {
            hssfStationSheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to delete a cell content is quite straightforward. You just need to get to the cell

```
cell.setCellType(CellType.BLANK);
```